# The right way to do a Python IRC bot?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, sockets, irc

So I'm starting to write a simple procedural Python IRC bot from scratch (i.e. raw sockets) and I'm trying to work out the best way of designing it.

Usually I have a big ol' while() loop that'll sit there and push data received from the socket into a buffer and I'll use a massive if/else statement to scan through the string (using regular expressions) to work out what to do with it.  I have a feeling that I shouldn't be doing that because it feels awful.

I decided to make a dictionary of regexes and their associated meanings, e.g.

```
regexes = {"^PING: (.+)": "incomming_ping",
           "more regex": "more meanings"}
```

and just use a for/in loop to search through the text and find out which regex matches it.  I've gotten this far, and I the first thing I thought was "okay, i can just make each 'procedure' to be called when a specific regex matches into a function, and call the appropriate function based on the meaning.  I'm either stuck with using a massive if/else statement, which i didn't want to do in the first place, or I could use some sort of Pythonic 'eval', which immediately sets off alarm bells.

Either way I'm screwed, and I can't think of a way to approach this without going fully OOP (I don't plan on doing this at the moment, don't ask why).

Any ideas?

Comment: thats how I did https://github.com/mouuff/MouBot

Comment: I know you said "from scratch", but you may want to look at Supybot if you haven't already. It's written in Python, and designed to be extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def incoming_ping():
    pass

regexes = {"^PING: (.+)": incoming_ping,
           "more regex": "more meanings"}
```

Instead of strings, use references to functions.

ps. If you're "serious" about the IRC bot thing, you might want to have a look at Twisted.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for!  I was thinking along those lines but I didn't know you could actually reference functions in dictionaries.  Thanks!

Comment: You can reference them *anywhere* - in Python, functions are first-class objects.

Comment: @Kye samplebias's solution is better and is the way it's usually done. Doing it this way gives you more freedom in what you want to accept as a command.

Answer (score 2):

Write a generic IRC protocol parser, which can be regexp-based.  It seems a bit redundant to write a separate regexp for each distinct command (`^PING\s, ^PRIVMSG\s`), when commands follow a more general pattern (`^[A-Z]\s`).

Then, once you've parsed a command, you can lookup the method/function which perform that command by using `getattr(obj, 'irc_%s' % command)`.

The advantage is that you don't need to maintain all your methods *plus* a mapping table with a pattern per command.

This is the technique used in [Twisted's IRC client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.0.0/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html):

```
def handleCommand(self, command, prefix, params):
    """Determine the function to call for the given command and call
    it with the given arguments.
    """
    method = getattr(self, "irc_%s" % command, None)
    try:
        if method is not None:
            method(prefix, params)
        else:
            self.irc_unknown(prefix, command, params)

def irc_JOIN(self, prefix, params):
    # perform the JOIN action
    ...

def irc_unknown(self, prefix, command, params):
    # unknown command
    ...
```